# adding more text to a query string

Tags: search

On a site I am developing, I need a "special search" function. The search page is called with a search query from a form with _GET parameters like this :
http://example.com/s=searchstring&s1=s1text1&s2=s2text1&s2=s2text2

In the search page itself (where the result will be), how can I concatenate the s1 and s2 arguments so the results for wordpress would be treated as if it receives: http://example.com/s=searchstring+s1text1+s2text1+s2text2

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use `set_query_var()` very very early, before the query is parsed and queried for, for example during the `pre_get_posts` action. Although thinking about it, if you're using `pre_get_posts` it's likely easier to do something like this (off the top of my head):

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || ! $query->is_search() )
        return;

    $query->set( 's', $query->get( 's' ) . sprintf( ' %s %s', $_GET['s1'], $_GET['s2'] ) );
});
```

Comment: Would add an `isset` in there on the `$_GET` params

Comment: Sure, `isset` or `empty`, maybe even validate them depending on what they are.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I modified the syntax slightly, adding ');' to have the correct syntax, but this does not have the right effect. I even try with a simpler function:add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function() {
 global $searchText;
 return set_query_var ( 's', $searchText );
} ); where $searchText is built before, without any success.

Comment: I just copied the code, replaced the `$_GET` variables with a hard-coded `foo` and `bar` and ran a search for `hello` on my site. Here's the result: https://cloudup.com/csNogjNYoT7

Comment: Thanks @kovshenin for your help. I was able to make it work now !